# Question regarding subscription confirmation emails

Tags: 2013-sp1, outbound-email, contact-sync

We are running SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR#1 and Java on the presentation side. When `contact.save(PageURI)` method is called the Page URI gets stored in the `subscription management` database on the presentation side. During contact sync this info is sent to the CMS server and an email based on the PageURI is sent to the contact.

In case `contact.save(PageURI)` method is called more than once within one sync cycle with different PageURI values, are all the PageURIs stored and synced back to the CMS or only the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one URI stored in the database, so if the saves happen in a very short time-frame only the last one will be sent. If a synchronization action happens to occur in between the saves, both e-mails will be sent.